# Why is this question not showing as protected?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, new-users, protected-questions

I put my answer as a comment here because there was no answer box, and the question was not even protected.

[Trying to quit smoking but co-workers want me to start again due to me being more irritable](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/127602/trying-to-quit-smoking-but-co-workers-want-me-to-start-again-due-to-me-being-mor#comment407588_127602)

Here is a screen shot of the bottom of the question, showing no answer box.

[image]

Here is a screen show of the top of the question, showing it is not protected.

[image]

I see no banner saying 'protected'. The word 'protected' doesn't appear anywhere on the page.

[image]

Here is another screen shot between the questions and the comments.

[image]

Comment: Interesting -- I see the protection notice, but if I view the question while logged out I don't.  You're logged in and do not see the notice?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question has in fact been protected; [this happened around about 07:00 UTC on 2019-01-31](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/127602/timeline#history_a04b4af3-8336-45dd-8351-282386aea4c2).

There is a [network-wide bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322971/protection-banner-missing-when-i-dont-have-enough-rep-to-answer-closed-and-loc) which means that the protection status is not shown if (and only if) you do *not* have enough reputation (on the specific site) to answer the question. (Credit to Monica Cellio for finding that bug report). As you do not have 10 reputation *on The Workplace*, you cannot answer the question so you are being hit by the bug.

The bug was fixed around 23:00 UTC on 2019-01-31.

Comment: I see no banner saying protected. 'Protected' doesn't even appear on the page. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm1ZI.png

Comment: @Chloe I see the banner-- it's there, between the question and comments on it.

Comment: Well, it *is* protected. I see it, everybody else sees it and the timeline shows it. Do you have an ad blocker or something which is hiding the banner?

Comment: I do not have an ad blocker. So it is a bug in the display? I added another screen shot showing between the question and the comments.

Comment: [There's a network-wide bug with display of protection status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322971/162102). :-(

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ah good find. TL;DR: the bug manifests only if you *don't* have enough rep to answer the question, if you do then it's all fine.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. `protected by Snow♦ 18 hours ago`